# Jasper Report PDF Encoding

Tags: encoding, jasper-reports

I am trying to generate or export to PDF a jasper report but I can't display `nihongo` or `japanese` characters. How do I fix this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Update

From the comment: 6 years later, the correct way to display character in Jasper Reports is using font-extensions, e.g. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/33941102/254109

### Original answer

Make a file `jasperreports.properties`, put it in the class path and set the PDF encoding.

```
net.sf.jasperreports.default.pdf.encoding=Cp1250
```

Or make base style in a report, set what you need, and all other styles derive from this style, i.e. they have an attribute style="base".

Comment: I have added `jasperreports.properties` with mentioned contents, somethings started to come but now it is showing "?" characters. Please help me on this.

Comment: 6 years later, the correct way to display character in jasper report is using font-extensions see for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33940126/how-can-i-display-%C2%A3%E2%84%A6%E2%82%AC%CE%B1%CF%80%E2%85%94-in-jasperserver-pdf-using-ireport/

Comment: @PetterFriberg you saved my life! After two days of the painful search for a solution, in the end, it was just a matter of adding `<pdfEncoding><![CDATA[Identity-H]]></pdfEncoding>` to my font-extension. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

You can also set "net.sf.jasperreports.default.pdf.encoding" in code like this:

```
JRProperties.setProperty("net.sf.jasperreports.default.pdf.encoding", "Cp1250");
```

Comment: I can not say it louder: thank you. I was fooling around with things like JRPropertiesUtil.getInstance(context).setProperty()...

A good advice though is to use jaspers property constants: http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/constant-values.html

And if you by any chance already have the possibility to hav a charset in your hands(eg: "windows-1250"), you can use the org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.common.EncodingMap.getIANA2JavaMapping(yourcharset) to get the analog "CP1250".

Comment: coming very late , but as 'JRProperties.setProperty' is deprecated and 'JRPropertiesUtil.getInstance(context).setProperty()' is not working do you have another solution

Answer (score 5):

You have to embed UTF-8 fonts in the PDF.

1. get the utf-8 fonts and place them on your classpath
2. for older jasper-reports version use a custom `style` and apply it to all texts
3. before printing, call `style.setPdfFontName("/com/package/fonts/times.ttf")`;

For newer versions the `PdfFontName` is deprecated instead of another way of doing this, but I can't find it now - look it up yourself.

Another workaround might be found [here](http://rkvsraman.blogspot.com/2009/05/indic-scripts-and-jasper-reports.html)

Answer (score 4):

I have faced same issue but with Eastern European characters. When i set a pdfEncoding property to Cp1250 then it started to work but unfortunately it didn't worked for french characters. Then I found this article which provides a very easy solution: http://jasperstarter.sourceforge.net/unicode-pdf-export.html

it was enough to set `fontName="DejaVu Sans"`

Answer (score 1):

Below approach will address indic font issues.
http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/fonts/index.html#fontextensions