# How to use RTF content is jasper report

Tags: html, jasper-reports, primefaces-extensions

I am using Jasper Report 5.6.0 + JSF 2.2 + Primefaces 5.2

My problem is in detail band (content) of the jrxml I am passing RTF from `pe:ckEditor` [here](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/sections/ckEditor/multipleEditors.jsf). This editor have many rich components e.g. tables, radio, fonts etc.

In generated document many styles escaped automatically. like table or font. While that text-field markup is html.

**More:** font will be changed if i generate html instead of pdf. and my rough guess is if any font that is not in JasperReport -> iText library it will escaped automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To render **RTF** text you use `markup="rtf"` on the `textElement`, however you will **not** be able to render tables, text alignment, box's ecc.

> **This feature is only for producing styled text.**, how the text looks (bold, size, color ecc.)

What are your options?

1. Convert to html and use the [HTML Renderer Component](http://community.jaspersoft.com/jasperreports-library/issues/4256), note neither this is perfect since it will renderer and image of your html (problem with overflow and size).
2. Create your own RTF component, I have not seen an RTF Renderer Component and I don't think there are any open tracker for this feature request in the [JasperSoft Community](http://community.jaspersoft.com/bug-tracker)
3. Parse the RTF in java and use dynamic jasper to generate your report (or subreport relative to the RTF)

When generating pdf, if font extension is not provided , iText will use (quoting [@Bruno Lowagie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1622493/bruno-lowagie)) "*its best effort*" to render your font, this often is not enough. Consider adding font-extension to your project

[Check list for rendering font in pdf using jasper report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34041619/jasper-reports-pdf-doesnt-export-cyrillic-values)

[How to add font extensions using iReport or JasperSoft Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33940126/how-can-i-display-%C2%A3%E2%84%A6%E2%82%AC%CE%B1%CF%80%E2%85%94-in-jasperserver-pdf-using-ireport/)

Note: If you are using the HTML Renderer Component this will not be needed since it is rendering an image.

Comment: I have to do it for tables, text directions, list, checkbox e.t.c. Actually all components in here http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/sections/ckEditor/basicUsage.jsf, I tired many things but not perfect. Do we have any other option in Jasper, Or I just simply move to XSLT which is pure HTML based (no limits)

Comment: @Sarz Note the HTML component will render and image (you will have problem with dimension, overflow ecc.) so it is not really no limits.. If you need no limits, I would have tried with dynamic jasper or directly generating the the jasper report via code. Example for the rtf generate a subreport (.jrxml) via code (implement the features as you like) and then included it main report.