# iReport Upgrade Problems

Tags: fonts, jasper-reports, upgrade, ireport

I recently upgraded from iReport 3.0.0 to iReport 5.6.0. After the upgrade some of the text in my report wouldn't show up in the generated PDF file. I messed around a bit and found out that on making the textfields bigger, the text shows up. But that is not a solution for me, since I have over 50 reports that would need editing. Also increasing the size of the textfield messes with my whole report.

I think it has something to do with the PDF font. In iReport 3.0.0 I used Helvetica as my font; but I learned that in iReport 5.6.0, the PDF font is deprecated.

I feel like this has also something to do with the fact that I converted .jasper files to .jrxml files in 5.6.0. I don't have any idea of how I can fix this. Could someone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Have you updated the jasper-report jar as well?

Comment: You should use font-extension to include your font correctly in pdf, please see for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34271686/jasper-report-truncates-text-before-filling-the-whole-text-field

Comment: see also this seems different but it always on how to render font correctly in pdf.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34041619/jasper-reports-pdf-doesnt-export-cyrillic-values

Comment: thanks @PetterFriberg! but I have a new problem now. Whenever i save the report, the textFieldExpression class attribute changes to a java.lang.string. Also, the compiler language does not save. I have to manually enter it each time I save the report. Is this a bug I am not aware of?

Comment: textFieldExpression attribute is not needed anymore (jasper report v5,6), as far as language it should save (there is a default settings in which language to start... but does not seem to function so well), need always to switch from groovy to java....

Comment: What settings do you in options >> compatibility?

Comment: I have Last Version. I tried with 3.1.0 but it doesn't work.