# How to add a symbol ₺ (Turkish Lira) in iReport

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

```
$P{DETAILPARAM} = " Tarihinden bu güne kadar <style isBold='true' pdfFontName='DejaVu Sans'>"+new java.text.DecimalFormat("#,##0.00").format($F{TOTAL_DEBT})+" ₺ </style> Borcunuz vardır."
Font = DejaVu Sans
```

This like add `$P{DETAILPARAM}` in parameter. And export PDF, but do not show "₺" this symbol.
What must I do?

Comment: Are you still having issues with this?

Comment: yes. I have the issues

Comment: You can not display the the symbol?, have you checked answer below... If you copy jrxml and it does not display it's probably a font issue?

Comment: This is the font extension jar I used in my example, www.jdd.it/stacktrace/DejaVuSerif.jar, set it in classpath and you will have same output as mine...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Turkish Lira](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turkish_lira_sign) has unicode `U+20BA` and since it fairly new (2012) you need to be sure that this unicode is supported by your selected font .

I tried with the font **dejavu-serif**, to understand how to download and install correctly see: [How can I display "$£Ω€απ⅔" in Jasperserver PDF using iReport?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33940126/how-can-i-display-%C2%A3%E2%84%A6%E2%82%AC%CE%B1%CF%80%E2%85%94-in-jasperserver-pdf-using-ireport)

**Result**

[image: Result]

**This was my jrxml code:**

```
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="FontTest" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="2347c131-1884-430a-b77f-59f08f896c8a">
    <parameter name="number" class="java.lang.Double" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[new Double(1000.23)]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <title>
        <band height="25">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="25" uuid="bc2ae040-f9af-4732-82fe-8fe8b71696bd"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="DejaVu Serif" size="14"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["\u20BA"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="₺ #,##0.00">
                <reportElement x="100" y="0" width="200" height="25" uuid="ee49d149-394b-4ac6-a0a2-6d207b0c8d89"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="DejaVu Serif" size="14"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{number}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```

**Some design notes:**

1. When formatting numbers it is better to apply `pattern`, since this will keep correct class if exported to for example excel.
2. I  could not achieve the pattern `"\u20BA #,##0.00"` even if this works directly in java, I need to further investigate this, seems like jasper report is doing a replacement of the "\" had to put the char directly in pattern (even if this is not recommend).

Answer (score 0):

While PDF export, you should be carefull at three steps.

first one, find a custom font that supports mentioned symbol.
second one, PDF Font Name should be null
third one, PDF Encoding should be Identity-H

no need to mention that "Embed this font in PDF document" should be checked.