# How to get non-english support when exporting to PDF?

Tags: pdf, fonts, jasper-reports

I am using JasperReport version 6.2

And I want to export report to PDF, but my report will not support languages different then English (other languages fields appear as blank),

This is my code for generating the report

```
JsonDataSource ds = new JsonDataSource(JRLoader.getInputStream(jsonFile));
JasperReport jasperReport = (JasperReport)  JRLoader.loadObject(jasperFile);
parameters.put(JRParameter.REPORT_FILE_RESOLVER, new SimpleFileResolver(new File(reportDirPath)));
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters, ds);
JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, outputFilePath);
```

I created a Font Extension using this tutorial: "http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/custom-font-font-extension"

[image]

I export to jar file and add to my project class path, but all fields that are not in English are Still blank

peter comment with this  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35127956/how-can-i-test-if-my-font-is-rendered-correctly-in-pdf) was very helpful, it help me realize if my font is supporting the desire language in the first place

Comment: Consider to test you font directly in pdf http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35127956/how-can-i-test-if-my-font-is-rendered-correctly-in-pdf and check this [check list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34287186/jasper-report-hindi-pdf/34287509#34287509)

Comment: Let me know if you get stuck on something

Comment: @PetterFriberg hey, the example provided in the link was very helpful (the first link), i noticed that open sans dose not support hebrew, i decided to use the google noto (https://www.google.com/get/noto/). i need to support something like 5 languages dynamically, that means something like 6 fonts, should i load 6 'font extension' jars into the classpath, how dose that will work?.  thank you

Comment: You need to change font dynamically?.... can't you find one font that supports them all? have you tried Dejavu sans?

Comment: Note I have suggested a duplicate of your current question (font did not support, same problem as in duplicate), no worry with duplicate this happens and gives more entry points to answer. If you feel its correct consider to accept.. For your new question I will try to give suggestion in comment if we don't find an agreement  you can also consider to post a new question.

Comment: ok i will create a new question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35631571/jasper-report-load-multiple-font-extension

Comment: Hey @PetterFriberg "Dejavu sans" was working in the itext provided example, but not as a Font Extension, can you help ?

Comment: You bet!, and its already provided in the jasper-report distribution you do not need to do nothing really....just add the jasper-report-font....jar to classpath and set correct fontName in jrxml

Comment: I'm sorry I'm insisting but I take great care of keep SO clean, for me its more important then rep points, so please tell me why you do not feel its a duplicated.

Comment: ok got it :), working with  "Dejavu sans"

Comment: thank you @PetterFriberg :-)

Comment: Your welcome, the duplicate why don't you answer great fellow... yes, no, don't care, don't bother me, what ever... : )

Comment: can you write an answer, at least copy on of the comment, so i can mark it as correct ?

Comment: You see the answer would be same as in duplicated and since I'm happy without gaining rep points posting duplicated answers, I'm more happy if you accept the duplicated.. Note: its not negative to accept duplicated its positive... (if you check the duplicated you will see that he had a problem with the font ttf similar as yours, so solution is same... switch font), If you like one of my answers you can always up vote those : )

Comment: Its all about creating a great place on SO, where its easy to find stuff...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here was that font (ttf) did not support the language (tested using this [How can I test if my font is rendered correctly in pdf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35127956/how-can-i-test-if-my-font-is-rendered-correctly-in-pdf)) so problem similar to [How can I render hindi correctly when exporting to pdf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34287186/))

**Solution:** Find a font that support the language(s) and use font-extension.

For how to switch font between languages see this follow up question: [Jasper report, load multiple Font Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35631571/jasper-report-load-multiple-font-extension)

<sup>//Community wiki since I would preferred duplicated but difficult in low-traffic tag</sup>