# Font and Encoding for Korean Language

Tags: jasper-reports, pdf-generation, locale, export-to-pdf

We are using *JasperReports* to export pdf. It's working fine for

English :

```
Font -> Helvetica
Encoding -> CP1252
```

Japanese :

```
Font -> KozMinPro-Regular
Encoding -> UniJIS-UCS2-H
```

But not working for Korean Languages.

I set font and encoding in java as foillows:

```
   JRDesignReportFont font = new JRDesignReportFont();
   font.setPdfEncoding("KozMinPro-Regular");
   font.setPdfFontName("UniGB-UCS2-H");
```

I need the exact Font and Encoding Names.

Please give your suggestions.

Comment: Use font-extensions, find a ttf that renders Korean and then check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34041619/jasper-reports-pdf-doesnt-export-cyrillic-values/,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33940126/how-can-i-display-%C2%A3%E2%84%A6%E2%82%AC%CE%B1%CF%80%E2%85%94-in-jasperserver-pdf-using-ireport and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35127956/how-can-i-test-if-my-font-is-rendered-correctly-in-pdf

Answer (score 0):

"KozMinPro-Regular" is Japanese FontName and "UniGB-UCS2-H" is Chinese encoding.

For Korean language

```
font.setPdfFontName("HYSMyeongJo-Medium");
font.setPdfEncoding("UniKS-UCS2-H");
```

Comment: Is there any restriction for using these font. When I tried I got some exception prints on my log.                                                                          Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: Could not load the following font : 
pdfFontName   : HYSMyeongJo-Medium
pdfEncoding   : UniKS-UCS2-H
isPdfEmbedded : false|

Comment: @VijayRaja You need to add iTextAsian.jar to classpath.

Comment: Thanks For the update. I checked the iTextAsian.jar and there is only Chinese and Japanese fonts properties file alone in jar. Hope need to include HYSMyeongJo-Medium.properties file and UniKS-UCS2-H.cmap

Comment: @VijayRaja hmm... It seems iTextAsian.jar includes Korean fonts and encodings...
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/i/Downloaditextasianjar.htm

Comment: Uno, May be we are using old version of jar. Need to update to latest.