# From where does the jasperreports engine refer to the fonts from?

Tags: pdf, fonts, jasper-reports

I've an application where I use jasper reports libraries for generating report from online. Whatever font I use other than Helvetica, to generate a pdf report, is a problem. I'm not able to detect from where the font is referred/loaded. I dont have any explicit classes for either Helvetica or Times-Roman.

Following is the error thrown:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: Could not load the following font : 
pdfFontName   : Times-Roman
pdfEncoding   : Identity-H
isPdfEmbedded : false
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.getFont(JRPdfExporter.java:2036) ~[jasperreports-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.getChunk(JRPdfExporter.java:1818) ~[jasperreports-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.getPhrase(JRPdfExporter.java:1787) ~[jasperreports-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.SimplePdfTextRenderer.getPhrase(SimplePdfTextRenderer.java:89) ~[jasperreports-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.SimplePdfTextRenderer.render(SimplePdfTextRenderer.java:99) ~[jasperreports-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportText(JRPdfExporter.java:2158) ~[jasperreports-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportElements(JRPdfExporter.java:861) ~[jasperreports-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportPage(JRPdfExporter.java:821) ~[jasperreports-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportReportToStream(JRPdfExporter.java:698) ~[jasperreports-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportReport(JRPdfExporter.java:420) ~[jasperreports-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
```

But for the same report if I give PDF font name as Helvetica, everything runs fine.

Can anybody please help me understand how this works ? Also, If I want to add some new font, where can I add it ?

Followed the steps to add a new font in jasper fonts jar ,  mentioned in below link

http://www.codesuggestions.com/java/jasper-reports/adding-custom-fonts-t...

Earlier error vanished. A new error popped up.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRStyledTextParser
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.<init>(JRBaseFiller.java:121) ~[jasperreports-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:88) ~[jasperreports-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:103) ~[jasperreports-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:61) ~[jasperreports-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.createFiller(JRFiller.java:179) ~[jasperreports-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:81) ~[jasperreports-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:446) ~[jasperreports-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:276) ~[jasperreports-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:745) ~[jasperreports-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
```

jasperreports-5.5.0.jar is present in the classspath of the application, still facing this error.

Comment: To add fonts you need to use font-extensions see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33940126/how-can-i-display-%C2%A3%E2%84%A6%E2%82%AC%CE%B1%CF%80%E2%85%94-in-jasperserver-pdf-using-ireport

Comment: Thanks for the response Petter. I've tried out the mentioned method of exporting .ttf of the font as a jar and adding it to the classpath. But, it did not work, I still get the Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRStyledTextParser
 error. Is there a specific name I should provide to the jar being created from iReports, or any name would do ?

Comment: What font are you using?, make sure it works with the itext library http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35127956/how-can-i-test-if-my-font-is-rendered-correctly-in-pdf. The java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError, says you are missing a library, but I need more stacktrace since in current I can't see which

Comment: I'm using arial font. In iReports generation of a pdf report with arial is not a problem. The problem is when I add it to my application.

Comment: So you are missing the font-extensions or another library in classpath, which library?, I need more stacktrace to understand [edit] question and ping me

Comment: I've exported arial.ttf as arial.jar from iReports and added it in the classpath. The error stacktrace is already updated, the **second one**. I directly call `JasperFillManager.fillReport()` from my class.

Comment: Could not initialize class net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRStyledTextParser, there is an exception below this, see if you can get some more info, its does not find a class when trying to instance the class

Comment: If you like me to guess I guess xml-apis, check that you have the distributed jars in your classpath

Comment: Thank you Petter. Finally I found out the problem and fixed. Have posted as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with me was that I had understood the exception wrong ! Hence following the wrong solutions.

The solution mentioned in the links that I followed was for addition of custom fonts for FontName attribute and not PDFFontName attribute.

Jasper's PDFExporter refers to fonts from iText.jar. Hence changing the getFont() method call in my class helped me.

```
font = FontFactory.getFont(
                pdfFont.getPdfFontName(),
                pdfFont.getPdfEncoding(),
                pdfFont.isPdfEmbedded(),
                jrFont.getFontSize() * fontSizeScale,
                pdfFontStyle,
                forecolor
                );
```

I changed this line and provided the absolute path for my font.ttf.

```
font = FontFactory.getFont(
                "D\\fonts\\Arial.ttf",
                BaseFont.IDENTITY_H,
                BaseFont.EMBEDDED,
                jrFont.getFontSize() * fontSizeScale,
                pdfFontStyle,
                forecolor
                );
```