# UTF-8 with JRPdfExporter is not working

Tags: java, internationalization, jasper-reports, export-to-pdf

I am adding my code here, JRPdfExporter not showing turkish characters.

```
JRPdfExporter pdfExporter = new JRPdfExporter();            
                response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename=\""+fileName+".pdf\""); //No I18N
                response.setContentType("application/pdf"); //NO I18N
                pdfExporter.setParameter( JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint );
                pdfExporter.setParameter( JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, ouputStream );
                pdfExporter.setParameter( JRExporterParameter.CHARACTER_ENCODING, "UTF-8" );
                pdfExporter.exportReport();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jasper Reports PDF doesn't export cyrillic values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34041619/jasper-reports-pdf-doesnt-export-cyrillic-values)

Comment: Another useful post: [How can I test if my font is rendered correctly in pdf?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35127956/876298)