# Unicode characters in Jasper Report

Tags: internationalization, jasper-reports, export-to-pdf

I have a JasperReports report template (.jrxml) which is being populated by Java code. Java code is fetching data from some DB, preparing the List and passing it as parameter to report. Now the problem is that DB content could be in different languages

Ex- there is one column in DB which looks like this

```
PersonName
=============
"Jeff Atwood"
"Jon Skeet"
"Дарин Димитров"
"BalusC"
"VonC"
"अनुभावा"
"段故障"
```

So when the template is being populated the out pdf file is not showing anything for *non English words*.

Properties being used:

```
Font name = default
PdfFontname = default
PdfEncoding = default
```

I tried searching for the solution but most of the answers are for Report Internationalization which involves resource bundle and font family. I am just using *Jaspersoft Studio 6.3.1* as eclipse plugin.

It would be great help if somebody could provide the solution or even indicate where to look for.

Comment: `So when the template is being populated the out pdf file is not showing anything for non english words.` - You should use *[Font Extensions](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/fonts/#fontextensions)*

Comment: yes the table cell is empty for non-english names[as in example]

Comment: Check the SO docs on [font-extensions](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/jasper-reports/5773/font-extensions)

Comment: @AlexK The font extension seems to be working. I tried roboto font which is working for some of  the languages then I got to know about noto sans which support all the languages that I need. But when I am using noto sans chars are not being rendered(I ve created the font extension and exported the jar correctly because same procedure worked for roboto). now I tried splitting the problem by follwing this [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35127956/how-can-i-test-if-my-font-is-rendered-correctly-in-pdf So now even in this example noto is not rendering. Please help, I have no idea wht to do

Comment: @PetterFribergThe font extension seems to be working. I tried roboto font which is working for some of the languages then I got to know about noto sans which support all the languages that I need. But when I am using noto sans chars are not being rendered(I ve created the font extension and exported the jar correctly because same procedure worked for roboto). now I tried splitting the problem by follwing this [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35127956/how-can-i-test-if-my-font-is-rendered-correctly-in-pdf So now even in this example noto is not rendering. Please help...