# Jasper report exporting problems in java jar application

Tags: java, jasper-reports, itext

I know this question was already asked but there was no accurate answer that solve my issue. This was my first time working with **jasperreports**, it works fine in the IDE but when i exported it into application the ***"PDF export manager"*** does not work properly in rendering the pdf of my report, almost 95 % of my report is not rendered in the generated pdf.

I hope someone who knows or is VETERAN in **jasperreports** could help me or if you have other alternatives for reporting in java that is very easy and robust please have me a link thank you in advance.

Comment: You are missing to provide a [mcve] so we could only guess not answer... My guess you are missing font-extensions... so your font is not rendered... this can be a nice check list for rendering text in pdf: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34041619/jasper-reports-pdf-doesnt-export-cyrillic-values/34044441#34044441

Comment: Hi sir @PetterFriberg i have used  arial font-family how do i export it together with the jar file?

Comment: You do as in the check list, create a font-extension (using and arial.ttf for the different style) or include jasper-report-font.jar and use deja vu...if you dont wan't to create your own font-extensions...

Comment: @PetterFriberg there na .please explain why is it like that?

Comment: Can't understand what you like me to explain, to export font correctly to pdf you need to include font-extension of the font you use. The only font you can use without creating your own font-extension is SansSerif ecc if you put in class path the jasper-report-font.jar you can use DejaVu Sans ecc.  Arial is not among these so if you need arial you need to create the extension in the post above there are link on how to create extensions.

Comment: "I know this question was already asked", where have you seen it?

Comment: Check also this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33940126/how-can-i-display-%C2%A3%E2%84%A6%E2%82%AC%CE%B1%CF%80%E2%85%94-in-jasperserver-pdf-using-ireport/33941102#33941102

Comment: There are link there on how to generate font extension on in both iReport and JasperSoft studio.

Comment: why is the output like that when i exported it to pdf?

Comment: as I sad I don't know [mcve], you need to show jrxml.., but I guess that you are missing font-extensions for your font... itext can not render the font..

Comment: but naturally it can be alot of other stuff as printWhenExpression etc...

Comment: @PetterFriberg Thanks allot you're right it was the font that got the exporter a problem thanks. :)

Comment: I have suggested a duplicate (since you had a duplicated,common problem), consider doing the community a favor accepting the duplicate (more or less I was correct before... ; )

Comment: @PetterFriberg Done. The question is now closed as a duplicate.